# Send Post Request over Cordova InAppBrowser

Tags: javascript, cordova, post, phonegap-plugins, inappbrowser

I am developing a cordova hybrid app (currently for android) and using the InAppBrowswer-Plugin.

I want to open a web page and login there using a post request (as it is currently done via Java in an actual Android application).

Somehow this does not work though and I cannot figure out why. This is the code I am using:

```
var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open("www.thesite.dummy", "_blank", "location=yes");

var postAsString = 'var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();'+
    'xhttp.open("POST", "'+url+'", true);'+
    'xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {alert("it worked")}};'+
    'xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");'+
    'xhttp.send("username=dummyUser&password=dummyPW")'
console.log(postAsString);

ref.executeScript({"code":postAsString});
```

As you can see I also console.log my "postAsString". If I copy this string and execute it in the console of www.thesite.dummy it actually works, but not in the InAppBrwoser

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37526321/cordova-inappbrowser-post-form-to-url to me

Comment: Would  make more sense to call the newer one the duplicate, but I agree. The questions are identical

Answer (score 8):

Just to help anyone who find this question through Google, the solution is [described at that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41185803/3424212) as said in the question comments.

The code, changing values for the specific context is below:

```
var pageContent = '<html><head></head><body><form id="loginForm" action="www.thesite.dummy" method="post">' +
'<input type="hidden" name="username" value="dummyUser">' +
'<input type="hidden" name="password" value="dummyPW">' +
'</form> <script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("loginForm").submit();</script></body></html>';
var pageContentUrl = 'data:text/html;base64,' + btoa(pageContent);

var browserRef = window.cordova.InAppBrowser.open(
    pageContentUrl ,
    "_blank",
    "hidden=no,location=no,clearsessioncache=yes,clearcache=yes"
);
```