# Cordova InAppBrowser post form to url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, post, inappbrowser

i'm trying to post values inappbrowser but no success.
it does open browser twice and no data posted.

```
   var options = {
        email: 'test@email.com',
        item_id: 1234,
        reference: 1234,
        item_descr: 'description',
        item_quant: 1,
        item_valor: 50 * 100
    };
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    var url = "https://testurl.com";
    form.setAttribute("method","post");
    form.setAttribute("action",url);
    for (var data in options) {
      var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
      hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
      hiddenField.setAttribute("name", data);
      hiddenField.setAttribute("value", options[data]);
      form.appendChild(hiddenField);
    }
    document.body.appendChild(form);
    var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, '_blank', 'location=yes');
    if(ref){
      form.submit();
    }
```

Answer (score 25):

Here's another way of posting a HTML form via the InAppBrowser using a dataUrl:

```
var pageContent = '<html><head></head><body><form id="loginForm" action="YourPostURL" method="post">' +
'<input type="hidden" name="key1" value="' + YourValue1 + '">' +
'<input type="hidden" name="key" value="' + YourValue2 + '">' +
'</form> <script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("loginForm").submit();</script></body></html>';
var pageContentUrl = 'data:text/html;base64,' + btoa(pageContent);

var browserRef = window.cordova.InAppBrowser.open(
    pageContentUrl ,
    "_blank",
    "hidden=no,location=no,clearsessioncache=yes,clearcache=yes"
);
```

Comment: what is btoa() ?

Comment: It's for encoding data using Base64: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding

Comment: I am trying above code but its not working, browser does not open in my device.

Comment: @SunilRawat: Did you try the examples for the InAppBrowser-plugin from it's documentation? Do they work or is it a general problem with the plugin and your device/app?

Comment: I tried it with InAppBrowser plugin, yes from document I am trying , I just want to pass a single paremeters from js to html using InappBrowser.

Comment: //Open as browser in device
        var openInAppBrowser = function(fields) { //alert(fields);   alert('Running in Device..'); 
                       
            
         //Post all required paremeters to the payu   
        iabRef = window.open('epayDevice.html', '_blank', 'location= no');
        iabRef.addEventListener('loadstart', function() {});

Comment: can you please assist me in this. I have spent lots of time to find the solution but no success.

Comment: It might be better to formulate your question as a new question on SO and link it here

Comment: it is not working for me. how to do this in phonegap app??

Comment: @ram12393 can you please post the solution?

Comment: @user94 can pleas tell me , r u using ionic or any other ?

Comment: @ram12393 hi, I am using Cordova (PhoneGap) app.

Comment: then it should be work perfectly. still r u facing problem

Comment: above solution makes error for me. I need to post values to payUmoney. i am using InAppBrowser for payment gateway.

Comment: @Jannis have you validated that this works in iOS? I'm getting blank inAppBrowser page with pageContentUrl string rendered at the bottom of the screen

Comment: @billy_comic: Not recently, no. inAppBrowser-plugin had some changes regarding Apple's depcrecation of UIWebview that might affect this. Anyone else running this on iOS recently?

Comment: @billy_comic I am facing a similar issue with Form Post, did you find any solution

Answer (score 9):

you can do it like this

```
var options = {
        email: 'test@email.com',
        item_id: 1234,
        reference: 1234,
        item_descr: 'description',
        item_quant: 1,
        item_valor: 50 * 100
    };

    var script = 'var form = document.createElement("form");';
     script += 'var url = "https://testurl.com";';
     script += 'form.method="post"';
     script += 'form.setAttribute("action",url);';
    for (var data in options) {
      script += 'var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");';
      script += 'hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");';
      script += 'hiddenField.setAttribute("name","' + data +'");';
      script += 'hiddenField.setAttribute("value","' + options[data] + '");';
      script += 'form.appendChild(hiddenField);';
    }
    script += 'document.body.appendChild(form)';
    var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, '_blank', 'location=yes');
script += 'form.submit();';
```

and then execute script in the inappbrowser using on the loadstop event like this

```
ref.addEventListener('loadstop', onLoadStopFunction);

onLoadStopFunction(params){
   ref.executeScript({ code: script }, executeScriptCallBack);
}
function executeScriptCallBack(params) {

    if (params[0] == null) {

        //error message
    }

}
```

there are many other ways to do it.

Comment: whats other method. ? I am not able to submit form in InappBrowser.. please advice some other methods

Answer (score 1):

You need to fill in the dynamic feild values on loadstop or load start event by using Execute Script.

First Bind the events , when you open the link:

```
{
  var url= 'yourURL';
  if( device.platform === "Android"){
         ref =cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, "_blank",'location=no,clearcache=yes,hardwareback=no,zoom=no');
  }else{
        ref =cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, "_blank",'location=no,clearcache=yes,closebuttoncaption=Go back to App,toolbar=yes,presentationstyle=formsheet');
  }


  ref.addEventListener('loadstart',onBrowserLoadStart);
  ref.addEventListener('loadstop',onBrowserLoadStop);
  ref.addEventListener('loaderror', onBrowserError);
  ref.addEventListener('exit', onBrowserClose);
}
```

Then on onBrowserLoadStop, check if its the right page to Post form:

```
function onBrowserLoadStop(event){


var cUrl= 'myformURL';
if(event.url===cUrl){

    var msg;
    var newHtml=YourFormHTML;
    var withoutScriptHtml = $(newHtml.bold());
    withoutScriptHtml.find('script').remove();


    msg=    " var formDiv = document.createElement('div'); formDiv.id='someFormDiv'; ";
    msg+=   " formDiv.innerHTML='" + withoutScriptHtml.html()+ "';" ;
    msg +=  " document.getElementById('outerDiv').appendChild(formDiv);"; //outerDiv should be on the html page residing at cUrl
    msg +=  " document.getElementById('yourFormName').submit();";
    //console.log("the message: "+ msg);


    ref.executeScript(
        {
            code: msg
        },
        function(values){
            console.log(JSON.stringify(values));
        }
    );


}
}
```

Answer (score -2):

From the 1 page:

```
window.localStorage.setItem('tempForm', JSON.stringify(form));
location.replace('page2.html');
```

2 page:

```
var passedForm = $.parseJSON(window.localStorage.getItem('tempForm'));
```

You can do that with all objects.